Is the projection of a diagonalizable matrix diagonalizable?
Let $V$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $A: V \rightarrow V$ be a diagonalizable, but not necessarily Hermitian, linear operator in $V$. Let $W \subset V$ be a vector subspace and $\Pi$ an orthogonal projection onto $W$. Is it true that $\Pi A \Pi$ is also diagonalizable?
If $A$ is Hermitian, then so is its projection onto anywhere, but I'm interested in the case when it's not. I'm most interested in the case when $V$ is infinite-dimensional and $W$ is finite-dimensional, but an answer for the case when both $W$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional would be immensely helpful as well.

No, not even in finite dimensions. For example, take $V = \Bbb{C}^3$, $W = \Bbb{C}^2 \times \{0\}$, and
$$A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0}.$$
Note that
$$\Pi = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}.$$
The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^3 - 1$, which is square-free, making $A$ diagonalisable. We also have:
$$\Pi A \Pi = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0},$$
a non-zero nilpotent matrix, which is not diagonalisable.

To add to Theo's answer, I found another example:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
And the projector is $$
\Pi = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
In this case, $A$ has distinct real eigenvalues, but $\Pi A \Pi$ is again not diagonalizable.
